# Change case with RegEx where there may be numbers in the string

Tags: javascript

I have this function to convert strings to title case,

```
export function toTitleCase(text) {
  const result = text.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
  return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1);
}
```

With camelCase the result is Camel Case.
The result is correct.

With camel23Case the result is Camel23 Case.
I would like the result to be Camel 23 Case

With camelCASE the result is Camel C A S E.
I would like the result to be Camel CASE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for sequences of uppercase letters or numbers, and add a space before them. Then replace the 1st lowercase letters with uppercase versions:

```js
const toTitleCase = (text) => text
  .replace(/([A-Z]+|[0-9]+)/g, ' $1')
  .replace(/\b([a-z])/g, (m) => m.toUpperCase());

console.log(toTitleCase('camelCase'));
console.log(toTitleCase('camel23Case'));
console.log(toTitleCase('camelCASE'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex - `/((?<=[a-z])[0-9A-Z])|(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]/g`

```
function toTitleCase(text) {
  var regex = /((?<=[a-z])[0-9A-Z])|(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]/g;
  const result = text.replace( regex, function(m){ return " " + m });
  return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function toTitleCase(text) {
  var regex = /((?<=[a-z])[0-9A-Z])|(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]/g;
  const result = text.replace(regex, function(m) {
    return " " + m
  });
  return result.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + result.slice(1);
}

console.log(toTitleCase("camel23Case"));

console.log(toTitleCase("camel23CASE"));
```

**Explanation**

- `((?<=[a-z])[0-9A-Z])` matches the following uppercase alphabet or character if previous character is lowercase alphabet
- `(?<=[a-z0-9])[A-Z]` matches only following alphabet if previous character is a either a lowercase alphabet or a number.